# How can I get the socket ID from an event in Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I want to know which client sent an event when it arrives on the server. For example:

```
var socket = require(socket.io')(port);

socket.on("ask question", function(data){
    var socketid = // ?

    //respond to sender
    socket.sockets.connected[socketid].emit("Here's the answer");
});
```

How can I get the socket ID of the event sender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server-side logic is a bit off.  The client connects and that's where the client socket is revealed and that's where you listen to events from a particular client.  Usually, it would look like this:

```
var io = require("socket.io")(port);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('ask question', function (data) {
        // the client socket that sent this message is in the
        // socket variable here from the parent scope
        socket.emit("Here's the answer");
    });
});
```

This is shown in the socket.io docs [here](http://socket.io/docs/).

Comment: My confusion was in the fact that I name io "socket", which made me think of that example as sending it to everyone.